# What is the search filter to see all open pull requests across all of your GitHub repositories

Tags: github, pull-request, dependabot

It can be useful to see all open pull requests in all repositories that one owns, not only the ones which one authored (which is prominently documented on the search bar).

An example: I have activated automated security updates for dozens of repositories.  Across my account there are now scores of PR's authored by **dependabot**.  I wish to list all these very similar PR's so I can review and (mostly) approve them conveniently. I want non-dependabot authored PR's as well because I know in some cases maintainers volunteered to make the updates with close scrutiny.  I prefer these PR's in most cases but still wish to review them.

Answer (score 2):

I think I got it :

`is:open is:pr user:<<username>>`

[image: illustration of filtered search for all open PR's across a user's repos]

Substitute your user or organization name for `<<username>>`

This came from [here](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-your-work-on-github/using-search-to-filter-issues-and-pull-requests) plus some experimentation on the [pulls page](https://github.com/pulls?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aopen+is%3Apr).